# Plane Tracked + Keyed video is misaligned when moving quickly

Tags: node-editor, tracking, compositing-nodes

I have a video that I used Plane Tracking on, to key out a green board and put a video inside it.

It's all working more or less correctly, but I notice that when the board moves quickly in the video, the video inside is pretty misaligned. I'm not seeing this problem when the board is moving slowly though.

As you can see below, the board is tracked fairly perfectly:

[image: pic1]

But if you see in the "Compositing" panel's preview, on the same frame, the board is misaligned:

[image: pic2]

Why is this happening?

Comment: most likely the trackers for the fast moving section are not accurately tracking. Use a larger search area for the tracker.

Comment: I quite literally moved the trackers, frame by frame, by hand, to track the dots (on the board) accurately, and also adjusted the plane with it. It seems that the plane tracking is misaligned in some way, although I can't figure out how.. It's perfect, I scrolled through every frame to check!

Comment: Tracking blurry footage is a nightmare, and something you should try to avoid as much as possible, as you need to match the motion blur for each of the elements (including the matte for the green screen. The tracking might indeed seem accurate, but the original image has no clear borders anymore. Why are you using a shutter speed of .1 in the plane track deform node?

Comment: I tried fiddling around the shutter speed values to between 0 and 5, all of which is still misaligned and clearly show the green part on the bottom. I think I'll just screw around with the actual tracking points, re-place them to be lower than they should, to make the bottom part extend more. But do you have any other suggestions? :(

Comment: The most common shutter speed is 0.5. Check also the matte generated by the keyer node. To troubleshoot unplug the image output from the pane deform and use the plane output to see where the error is happening.

Comment: I can see that the frames, for some reason, repeats a single frame (so two identical frames in a row) at some times, which clearly screws up the tracking (as the visuals show two identical frames in a row but the auto-tracker tracks the second frame as if it's the continuous frame). Why is this happening? My frame rate is 29.97, but I think I tracked the footage at 24fps (default). Do I need to track the whole thing again, with the settings at 29.97fps again?? Oh no.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109718/discussion-between-susu-and-beardwix).

Comment: Chat is not working. You should not track at a different framerate! Blender is quite dumb when it comes to temporal interpolation in  video. It can only deal with a single timebase.

Comment: Yes, many many regrets. Which leads me to the other question I asked; I think the answer should be quite simple on that one, could you go take a look? :)

Comment: Also if your video is using mp4  with a long GOP blender will not track correctly. Try converting the video to an image sequence.