# How can I make the plane track of a single frame move separately from the others?

Tags: tracking

I've encountered a problem in my work. (As can be seen in detail in my previous question)
[https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183768/plane-tracked-keyed-video-is-misaligned-when-moving-quickly]
The plane tracks are acting strange and offset, for some reason.
All the plane tracks are correct as can be seen in the composition panel, but in the "Tracking" panel's preview, it's being superimposed incorrectly.

I've given up trying to find a solution, and have actually found a small workaround; Distorting the plane track on those certain frames, so I can manually adjust it to fit the frame.

But now, when I move the plane track for one frame, the entire project's plane track gets distorted to the extent that I changed it.

Is there some sort of "tracking marker", so I can change the plane track for just that frame (or those several frames) without disturbing the rest of the project's frames, which have the correct plane track? "Add marker" doesn't seem to do anything, for some reason..

Thank you.

Comment: When adding a reference to another question please put the link as part of the text. If you distort the plane track it will distort it for all of the frames unless you add keyframes to the shape.

Comment: Now that's what I'm asking; I tried adding keyframes, but I don't think I'm doing it properly.. How do I add keyframes?

Comment: @susu even if I turn on "Auto Keying" or something, it still distorts for all frames. How can I add keyframes, or the equivalent of it?? This is driving me nuts. Looking up about keyframes on Google leads to results that don't match my workspace!